# SSRS - Plot events and Time across x-axis for different equipment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm try to create a Graph that has different equipment down the y-Axis then shows different events for each piece of equipment by how long they took on the x-Axis. each event has its own colour. as you can see in the image i have a each bar with its colours for events. what i would like to do is have the time across the bottom. this is a 24hours period 7am to 7am. ideally have each event start where it is supposed to start but if it was just each group starting at each location that would do.
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfbY9.jpg)

the data i'm useing look like this

```
+----------------------+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
|       eventID        |              events              | time  | endTime |
+----------------------+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
| Wai30520151031202445 | Waiting                          | 20:24 | 01:10   |
| Bog30520151031200316 | Bogging - Conventional-Prod Ore  | 20:03 | 20:24   |
| Wai30520151031191951 | Tramming - Loader                | 19:19 | 20:03   |
| Wai30520151031190825 | Waiting - Breakdown/Maintenance  | 19:08 | 19:19   |
| Una30520151031190000 | Unaccounted                      | 19:00 | 19:08   |
| Una26720151031180139 | Unaccounted                      | 18:01 | 19:00   |
| Wai26720151031180122 | Waiting                          | 18:01 | 18:01   |
| Bog26720151031154121 | Bogging - Conventional-Prod Ore  | 15:41 | 18:01   |
| Wai26720151031151041 | Waiting                          | 15:10 | 15:41   |
| Bog26720151031150337 | Bogging - Conventional-Prod Ore  | 15:03 | 15:10   |
| Wai26720151031143906 | Waiting                          | 14:39 | 15:03   |
| Bog26720151031143126 | Bogging - Conventional-Prod Ore  | 14:31 | 14:39   |
| Wai26720151031123750 | Waiting                          | 12:37 | 14:31   |
| Bog26720151031122809 | Bogging - Conventional-Prod Ore  | 12:28 | 12:37   |
| Wai26720151031115324 | Waiting                          | 11:53 | 12:28   |
| Bog26720151031114426 | Bogging - Conventional-Prod Ore  | 11:44 | 11:53   |
| Wai26720151031111933 | Waiting                          | 11:19 | 11:44   |
| Bog26720151031104732 | Bogging - Conventional-Prod Ore  | 10:47 | 11:19   |
| Wai26720151031104426 | Waiting                          | 10:44 | 10:47   |
| Bog26720151031104003 | Bogging - Conventional-Prod Ore  | 10:40 | 10:44   |
| Wai26720151031103933 | Tramming - Loader                | 10:39 | 10:40   |
| Wai26720151031103616 | Tramming - Loader                | 10:36 | 10:36   |
| Bog26720151031103630 | Bogging - Conventional-Dev Waste | 10:36 | 10:36   |  |
+----------------------+----------------------------------+-------+---------+
```

to get the above graph i have the query in ssrs of

```
SELECT
    "Event" = (Case WHEN e.events like 'Tram%' THEN 'Tramming'
    WHEN e.events LIKE 'Bog%' or e.events LIKE 'Load%' or e.events = 'Dump' or e.events = 'Ground Support' or e.events = 'Drilling' or e.events = 'Rehab' or e.events = 'Rattling' THEN 'Operational'
    WHEN e.events = 'Unaccounted' THEN 'Unaccounted'
    ELSE 'Waiting'
    END)
    ,e.[time]
    ,p.equipmentID 
    ,CAST(sum(datediff(n, time, endTime)) AS decimal(10,2)) / 60 AS 'Time Taken'
FROM
    [events] e JOIN plod p ON e.plodID = p.plodID
WHERE
    e.time > DATEADD(hh, 7, @startTime)
    and e.endTime < DATEADD(hh, 31, @endTime)
GROUP BY
    e.events
    ,e.[time]
    ,p.equipmentID
order by time desc
```

Comment: I had to do something very similar in SSRS. It was suprisingly difficult. The only way I could do it was use a stacked graph, which each stacked segment representing a duration. So your event list can't have any holes . Then you need to add some custom code to SSRS to force the same event types to use the same colours. Otherwise every new segment just gets a different colour every time. I could not find a way to use to actual time component (i.e. 07:33) to place the segment on a graph. You'll need to add _duration_ and stack it.

Comment: The downside of this is you have to 'manufacture' the scale on the axis because I couldn't get SSRS to natively represent 0 seconds as 7am and 84,600 seconds as 7am the next day. But there doesn't seem to be a way to create the gant chart type graph that you want by using the times attached to the events.